# Mojarra 2.1 vs 2.2 - p:fileUpload InvalidContentTypeException on Form Submission

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2, mojarra

Can someone explain to my why you could submit a form in Mojarra 2.1 that contained a p:fileUpload + other fields like p:inputText, but this is not possible in 2.2?  I completely understand that it is a best practive to have p:fileUpload components on their own forms with multipart/form-data set.  With that being said, there are times when you might need to include a p:fileUpload as a member of a larger form.  For example:

[image: Example where upload is included in larger form]

Here is JSF 2.1, I used a single form for all elements and it works fine, but in JSF 2.2 the following error is thrown:

```
 Apr 10, 2014 10:17:38 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
 WARNING: javax.servlet.ServletException:      org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

If I broke the above into three forms it is then more difficult to have the top text area and the bottom settings section all updated with the unified "Update" button because they are separate forms.  Is there anyway to restore the 2.1 behavior in 2.2?  Is this a bug in 2.2 or the intended behavior, because I didn't see if documented anywhere that this would break when migrating to 2.2.